# How to allow PUT \ DELETE method in nginx to pass it in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, nginx, webdav

I have a problem with nginx server.
I Got index.php file

Server: Nginx + php-fpm8.1, with config:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ2Nz.png

I allow DELETE and PUT methods by dav_methods param and execute index.php with DELETE method type, but after request index.php was deleted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting dav_methods inside location?

```
location /test {
    dev_mothods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
}
```

Comment: I stopped on moment, where i delete dav_methods parametr, and change url:
from site/folder/
to site/folder/file
why it's not work by default with directories and index.php - i still dont know